# Error when using Aurelia compose tag when specifying view attribute only

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to load a view in to Aurelia using the compose template with the only the view attribute specified. ie.

```
<compose view="./test.html"></compose>
```

As soon as I add the above tag to and existing view I get the error message below.

```
UseView is not defined↵ at Function.normalize (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.10.2/view-strategy.js:40:27)`.
```

How can I use the compose element to load in a remote template?

Comment: This is a bug in the most recent release.  Path should be released today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @PW Kad this bug has now been resolved.  Some really quick work by the aurelia team there!

https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/54